# Mongodb query to group by multiple fields and filter

Tags: mongodb

I want to be able to group each "Place" to show over time, how many "PatientIds" they are seeing on a given day and then be able to filter this by what the action is.

Basically Total Patients on y-axis, Date on x-axis and then a filter or stacked chart to show the action. I also thought about a mapreduce, but have never done that in mongo

I can't figure out the correct mongo query. Right now I have:

```
db.collection.aggregate({"$group":{_id:{place:"$place",date:"$date",action:"$action",count:{$sum:1}}},{$sort:{"_id.date":1,"_id.place":1}})
```

However, this is just listing out the data. I tried to do a match on all places, but that didn't give me the results I was looking for either. Any ideas?

Example json:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(""),
    "patientId" : "100",
    "place" : "1",
    "action" : "DIAGNOSED",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-01-20")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(""),
    "patientId" : "101",
    "place" : "1",
    "action" : "PATIENT IN",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-01-20)
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(""),
    "patientId" : "200",
    "place" : "2",
    "action" : "MEDICINE",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-01-05")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(""),
    "patientId" : "300",
    "place" : "2",
    "action" : "DIAGNOSED",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-01-31")
}
```

EDIT - mapreduce

```
> var map = function(){emit(this.place,1)}
> var reduce = function(key,values){var res = 0;values.forEach(function(v){res+=1});return{count:res};}
> db.new.mapReduce(map,reduce,{out:"mapped_places"});
{
    "result" : "mapped_places",
    "timeMillis" : 88,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 4,
        "emit" : 4,
        "reduce" : 2,
        "output" : 2
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
> db.mapped_offices.find({})
{ "_id" : "1", "value" : { "count" : 2 } }
{ "_id" : "2", "value" : { "count" : 2 } }
>
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what the problem is but your query has syntax error. Should be `db.collection.aggregate({"$group":{_id:{date:"$date",place:"$place",action:"$action"},count:{$sum:1}}},{$sort:{"_id.date":1,"_id.place":1}})`. Please consider adding expected output to the post and input if any.

Comment: I want to total the number of patients per date per place. So, place:"1", has 2 claims on 2017-01-20, but there are two different actions so when I make the chart I want to be able to view all at once or by a certain action

Comment: So you just need to pass the match filter in case of certain action. Something like `db.collection.aggregate({$match:{action:"someaction"}}, {"$group":{_id:{date:"$date",place:"‌​$place"},count:{$sum:1}‌​}},{$sort:{"_id.date‌​":1,"_id.place":1}})`. For all actions the query I posted in the previous comment should work.

Comment: I'm updating the comment with a mapreduce function to see if there is any way to add the date to this.

Comment: Also, in what you are saying I need to match all the actions, which I don't know how to do in a $match

Comment: There is no need to use map reduce. What output do you get when you run aggregation queries and how it is different from expected output ? Btw, to match all actions you don't pass any match filter which will run the aggregation query over all the documents.

Comment: I'm getting the total by date, but not separate for each place. I am able to get it for a specific place. I need to express route this information to an ejs file.

Comment: It is still little unclear. You get `{ "_id" : { "date" : ISODate("2017-01-05T00:00:00Z"), "place" : "2", "action" : "MEDICINE" }, "count" : 1 }` when you run the first query. Is this not what you need ? It will be easier to understand if you can add the expected json to the post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152075/discussion-between-karmesto-and-veeram).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "date": "$date",
        "place": "$place"
      },
      "actions": {
        "$push": "$action"
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$actions"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "_id.date": 1,
      "_id.place": 1
    }
  }
]);
```

This should output something like

```
{ "_id" : { "date" : ISODate("2017-01-20T00:00:00Z"), "place" : "1"}, "count" : 2, "actions" : "PATIENT IN"  }
{ "_id" : { "date" : ISODate("2017-01-20T00:00:00Z"), "place" : "1"}, "count" : 2, "actions" : "DIAGNOSED"  }
```